# What wrong with my code in C# windowsform

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to do is to enter items and its price in a listbox 
and finally capture the total price of the items

This is the code that I have so far

```
 private void btnItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Market super = new Market();
        //  double total = 0;
        super._items = txtItems.Text;
        txtItems.Text = string.Empty;
        super._price = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrice.Text);
        txtPrice.Text = string.Empty;

        lstShow.Items.Add(super._items + " $ " + super._price);


    }

    private void btnPrice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Market super = new Market();
         lstShow.Items.Add("---------------------------------");
         decimal suma = 0;
         foreach (var item in lstShow.Items)
         {
             decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(item); //OJO solo para Winforms y si se metieron los items con un formato compatible con Decimal
             suma += d;
         }
         txtTotal.Text=(suma.ToString());

    }
```

but show this exception :(

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Additional information:

```
Input string was not in a correct format
```

Comment: Add the exception's stacktrace to the question text.

Answer (score 2):

A wild guess it's that you get the error trying to convert this:

```
lstShow.Items.Add("---------------------------------");
```

to a decimal

```
Convert.ToDecimal(item);
```

as it's clearly not. Remove that value and try again or if you absolutely want to keep it in the list try using `Double.TryParse(item);` instead. See the documentation for [Double.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Well, right but it is very unlikely that just this will solve the problem. What is that `_items` added before the price in the listbox?

Comment: @Steve Indeed, I just saw the most obvious first, but you're right, there might be other issues as well.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to change your class Market to add an override of the ToString method

```
public class Market
{
     public string _items {get;set;}
     public string _price {get;set;}

     public override string ToString()
     {
         return this._items + " $ " + this._price
     }
}
```

Now when you add items to the listbox add directly the Market instance

```
private void btnItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Market super = new Market();
    .....
    lstShow.Items.Add(super);
}
```

The listbox will call the `ToString()` method of the class `Market` showing your data in the format required, but every item in the ListBox is a Market instance not a simple string. This will allow
the following code in the calculation method

```
suma = 0;
foreach (Market item in lstShow.Items)
{
    suma += item._price;
}
txtTotal.Text=suma.ToString();
```

Of course remove the String added at the end or just create a new Market with this

```
Market m = new Market();
m._items = "----------------------------------------";
m._price = suma;
lstShow.Items.Add(m);
```